# Postfix ignoring SASL with dovecot -how to debug?

Tags: postfix, authentication, email-server, sasl, saslauthd

I recently upgraded my server (Ubuntu 12.03) and today I noticed that SMTP is not offering authentication anymore.

My setup is using virtual mailboxes + MySQL.

Telnet session:

```
telnet mail.mydomain.net 25

Connected to mail.mydomain.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo test-domain.com
250-mail.mydomain.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 402400000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

However, I cannot figure where to debug the issue. (EDIT: luckily, relaying is still forbidden, my test was flawed).

My relevant postfix configuration:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes 

# Strip internal IPs and hostnames
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, permit_mynetworks

#virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
#virtual_maildir_extended = yes

proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps

virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
#smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

And the relevant bits from Dovecot (2.x):

```
ssl_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

auth_mechanisms = plain login

service auth {
    user = root 
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
    } 
    unix_listener auth-master {
        user = vmail
        mode = 0600
    }
}

passdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}


userdb {
    driver = static
    args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
}
```

/etc/default/saslauthd:

```
 START=yes
 DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
 NAME="saslauthd"
 MECHANISMS="pam"
 MECH_OPTIONS=""
 THREADS=5
 OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
```

/etc/pam.d/smtp:

```
auth    required   pam_mysql.so user=mailadmin passwd=PASSWORD host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=users usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=mailadmin passwd=PASSWORD host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=users usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
```

The same setup works on a Debian Wheezy VM, so I'm not sure where the error lies. Notice that authentication on the IMAP / mail server side works perfectly.

Comment: no warnings/errors in the maillog?  (and why are you configuring saslauthd if you're using dovecot sasl?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the upgrade changed my configuration without noticing.

Setting things to

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_unauth_destination
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname
   reject_invalid_hostname
   reject_unauth_pipelining
   reject_unknown_sender_domain
   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
   reject_non_fqdn_sender
   reject_unknown_sender_domain
   check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

Restored the previous behavior (specifically, `permit_mynetworks` is no longer present in smtpd_sender_restrictions).